# JS Change form action upon select change doesn't work with .trim()

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, forms, trim

I have a form that I want to change the action of as a result of the user selecting an option from a `<select></select>` dropdown.

Here is my form:

```
    <form role="form"  method="post" id="switch-customer-form" class="switch-customer-form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
            <select class="form-control customers-dropdown" id="customers-dropdown" name="form_customers">
                {% for c in customers %}
                    <option{% if customer == c %} selected="true"{% endif %}>{{ c }} - {{ c.id }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select> 
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
            <input type="submit" value="View Calendar" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
        </div>


    </form>
```

Here is my (non-working) JS:

```
$("#customers-dropdown").change(function() {

    var action1 = "/ac/calendar/";
    var action2 = "/2014/12/";

    var customer = $(this).val();
    var customer_split = customer.split("-");
    var customer_id = customer_split[1].trim();

    var final_action = action1 + customer_id + action2;

    alert(final_action);

    $("#switch-customer-form").attr("action", final_action);

});
```

The issue I am having is upon adding `.trim()` to the `customer_id` variable initialization. For some reason when adding this function it no longer changes the form's `action`. Without `.trim()` it does change the action correctly however there is extraneous whitespace that causes the link to not direct to the appropriate page.

Is there something in `.trim()` causing this? Is there a more ideal way to remove the whitespace from that variable? Thanks for your help.

UPDATE (for clarity):

This is the only JS that I have gotten to successfully change the form action, although it still includes an extra whitespace:

```
$("#customers-dropdown").change(function() {

    var action1 = "/ac/calendar/";
    var action2 = "/2014/12/";

    var customer = $(this).val();
    var customer_split = customer.split("-");
    var customer_id = customer_split[1];

    var final_action = action1 + customer_id + action2;

    alert(final_action);

    $("#switch-customer-form").attr("action", final_action);

});
```

This is without adding a value to the `<option>` tag. Upon doing so I encounter the same issue where it does not update the form action and simply posts to the current page.

Comment: As arconmon says, you should add an explicit `value` attribute to the option element and just use that.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be easier to do it this way? (Using the id as the value of the select options)

```
<form role="form"  method="post" id="switch-customer-form" class="switch-customer-form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
            <select class="form-control customers-dropdown" id="customers-dropdown" name="form_customers">
                {% for c in customers %}
                    <option{% if customer == c %} selected="true"{% endif %} value="{{c.id}}">{{ c }} - {{ c.id }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select> 
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
            <input type="submit" value="View Calendar" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
        </div>


    </form>

$("#customers-dropdown").change(function() {

    var action1 = "/ac/calendar/";
    var action2 = "/2014/12/";

    var customer = this.value;

    var final_action = action1 + customer + action2;

    alert(final_action);

    $("#switch-customer-form").attr("action", final_action);

});
```

**UPDATE**

> This is without adding a value to the  tag. Upon doing so I
>   encounter the same issue where it does not update the form action and
>   simply posts to the current page.

You're being redirected to the same page because the change event hasn't been triggered and there's no action in the form. If the change event would be triggered, the action would change and it would work.

You need to add an action to the form or add javascript to change the action to the option marked as selected when the DOM is ready.

For instance, on DOM ready:

```
var changeAction = function(id) {
    var action1 = "/ac/calendar/";
    var action2 = "/2014/12/";    

    var final_action = action1 + id + action2;

    $("#switch-customer-form").attr("action", final_action);
};

changeAction($("#customers-dropdown").val());// On document ready, change action to selected item.
$("#customers-dropdown").change(function () {// On change event, change action as well
    changeAction(this.value);
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yw5nnk0y/4/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, `.value` didn't work but `.val()` did. Unfortunately even without `.trim()` now it still is not updating the form action.

Comment: @apardes Actually this.value works as is the same as $(this).val(). Funny you say that because when the change event triggers, it changes the action. You can see it here http://jsfiddle.net/yw5nnk0y/2/

Comment: Thanks for the update, I see it is working in your fiddle but I am still having difficulty. I have in fact confirmed that the change event is triggered with the `alert(final_action)`. The alert is displayed and I have even tried moving it after `$("#switch-customer-form").attr("action", final_action);` where it still displays the alert.

Comment: @apardes do you have more than one form in the page with the same id? Do you change the action in some other part of your code? Honestly, it should work without problem...